# ionic 3 Headers

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Everytime I try to build the app I get a huge error. I'm trying to POST to my MySQL using API.

2. Does localstorage work with MySQL over online server?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


/*
  Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

let apiUrl = 'http://dev.sonetine.com/restserver/api/register';

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');

  }

 postData(credentials, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let headers =  {headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})};

      this.http.post(apiUrl, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }

}
```

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Comment: please ask one question in a post and paste error as text

Answer (score 1):

I do like this-

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN': (this.tokenProvider.token) });
```